# Как найти строку в Python и вывести её полностью

Tags: python

Делаю голосового ассистента и нужен поиск по файлу и вывод всей строки!
То-есть. Пользователь пишет: "Слово" и программа ищет по файлу строку с этим словом и выводит её полностью!. Как это организовать?

Comment: Расскажите как устроен файл? Есть ли строки с одинаковыми словами?3

Comment: Читать файл построчно, если в строке есть слово - выводить строку.

Comment: Нет не должно быть!

Comment: Эникейщик, я знаю что надо делать так, но не знаю как это релаизовать!

Comment: Требуется ли регистрозависимость?

Answer (score 0):

```py
word = input()

with open('file.txt') as f:
    for row in f:
        if word in row:
            print(row)
```

где `file.txt` - название/путь к Вашему файлу.